# The meaning of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for an implicit curve $F(x, y) = c$ at a point which is not at the curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, plane-curves

What is the meaning of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $$xy^2 + x^2 - \frac{y}{x} = 2$$ at the point $(1,1)$ which is not at the curve? I know if the point is on the curve the derivative is the slope of the tangent at that point.

Comment: It means the slope of the curve $xy^2+x^2-\frac{y}{x}=1$ at $(1,1)$ :)

Comment: but the point is not on the curve ?

Comment: The point is on the new curve that I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: ah but that is not the question :\ . I asked this question since am thinking about is it acceptable to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for a curve at a point which is not on the curve.

Comment: @Ameryr: You asked for the meaning. Thomas told you what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression on the l.h.s. of the equation is of the form $$F(x, y) = c,$$ and differentiating gives $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 .$$ In particular, $c$ plays no role, so we can interpret $$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right\vert_{(x_0, y_0)}$$ as the slope of the tangent line to the unique level curve of $F(x, y)$ that passes through $(x_0, y_0)$, namely, the curve $$F(x, y) = F(x_0, y_0) .$$
(This statement comes with the usual caveats about differentiability and degeneracy of curves.)

Comment: Thanks very much, I am not very good at Calculus III. I must review it.

Comment: @Ameryr This is anyway a good and natural question. The key observation is just that $c$ doesn't appear in the expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, so (regarded as a function of $(x, y)$) it doesn't "know which level curve it's on."